# Aptana 3 app explorer right mouse click not working

Tags: macos, aptana

While using the Aptana 3 App explorer or Project explorer, the right mouse submenu does not always work.

On some files/folders it works but others it does nothing. It seems random to me. It's not always the same files/folders.

Restarting Aptana usually makes it work again.

Anyone having the same issue or found a workaround?

I'm on Mac OSX Lion.

**UPDATE**
After clearing the logfile and waiting for the problem to occur again, nothing noteworthy seems to be found in the logfile.

```
!SESSION 2011-08-24 08:09:21.674 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/maurice/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/maurice/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2011-08-24 08:09:27.612
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
```

Comment: Is there anything in the log (Help > Aptana > View Log File)?

Comment: sorry I didn't notice your message. Yes, there is a LOT in the logfile. I will clear it and post it after.

Comment: problem occurred again, no exceptions to be found, I posted full logfile.

Comment: same problem here. seems to occur on large projects? - smaller projects don't seem to be affected. maybe a memory problem (e.g. max assigned to java)

Comment: It happens to me too regardless of the size of the project.

Comment: 2 year passed, but problem still exists. build 3.6.0.201407100658 on Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon. Usually it works only a few times at the begining, 3-5, up to 10. Then stops working untill restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ticket filed on it in Aptana Studio JIRA: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3544, and it was caused by the underlying Eclipse issue described here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340954.

The underlying issue is addressed in Eclipse 3.7.1, and since the nightly Aptana Studio build has moved to be based on 3.7.1, it is fixed there as well.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning! Not sure if it's related, but checked it anyway. Still happening in build: 3.0.9.201202141038, which is the current stable.. Will keep checking (stable) releases.

Comment: Yeah, 3.0.9 is still based on Eclipse 3.6.2.  3.1, which is currently the nightly and will be released in a month or so, is based on 3.7.1.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will wait for the next update and let u know if it has been fixed.

Comment: I personally haven't experienced this problem in quite a while. I guess you're right and this was a fixed bug. Thanks!

Comment: I have just installed a fresh aptana on a fresh mac book pro and i'm not able to use the right click at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Java is needed to run Aptana. So if you have big projects, then you probably just need to increase the memory that Java has got access to. (It is by default only limited to 64MB).

Check out the link below for instuctions on how to do this:

http://blogs.stockcharts.com/step_by_step/2009/02/increasing-your-java-memory-so-you-can-annotate-large-charts-mac.html

I hope this takes care of your problem! Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. It sounds like what you say might help in solving this issue.
When I open `deployment.properties` though, it is a very small file, containing just 7 lines. Along them is a comment saying:
`# Java on Mac OS X does not maintain an installed JRE list in this file.
# Use /usr/libexec/java_home to obtain a $JAVA_HOME path.`. It looks like this is not the right file. Would you happen to know?

Comment: No, Im not sure.. sorry... Certainly sounds like a memory issue though. I hope you get it fixed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

He, found dirty hack. Right click on folder, then rapidly move mouse pointer to editors window away from explorer. For some reason it opens there